# What loads nft_compat

Tags: nftables, alma-linux

I am running AlmaLinux 9, and on boot I see warning

```
Warning: Deprecated Driver is detected: nft_compat will not be maintained in a future major release and may be disabled
```

but what is loading that driver?  I have firewalld service disabled.  I want to eliminate this warning (properly).

Additional info:

```
[root@server ~]# lsmod | grep  nft_compat
nft_compat             20480  14
nf_tables             278528  98 nft_compat,nft_counter,nft_chain_nat
nfnetlink              20480  2 nft_compat,nf_tables


[root@server ~]# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
NETAVARK_FORWARD  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* netavark firewall plugin rules */

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain NETAVARK_FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.88.0.0/16         ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.88.0.0/16         0.0.0.0/0

Chain NETAVARK_ISOLATION_2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain NETAVARK_ISOLATION_3 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
NETAVARK_ISOLATION_2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Does `lsmod | grep  nft_compat` show if it is used by any other modules?  Are you using anything that needs the legacy `iptables` interface?

Comment: I have added requested info above.  I don't explicitly use iptables,netavark seems to be related to podman (containers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the message itself: it's not an upstream kernel message, it's a specific message added in AlmaLinux 9 (and probably inherited from RHEL 9).

The `nft_compat` module is the compatibility layer allowing to run *iptables* over *nftables* and still use non-nftables modules.

> [`CONFIG_NFT_COMPAT`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NFT_COMPAT.html): Netfilter x_tables over nf_tables module
>
> [...]
>
> - modules built: `nft_compat`
>
> **Help text**
>
> This is required if you intend to use any of existing x_tables
> match/target extensions over the nf_tables framework.

Any xtables module that is used by `iptables-nft` instead of having `iptables-nft` translate the *iptables* rule into a native-only *nftables* rule will need `nft_compat` to work.

Starting from a clean VM running nothing network-related and thus not having `nft_compat` loaded, almost anything that is not empty will load it.

This doesn't:

```
iptables-nft -A -j ACCEPT
```

As it's translated purely into *nftables* code:

```shell
# uname -r
6.1.0-0.deb11.5-amd64
# iptables -V
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables)
# iptables -A -j ACCEPT
# nft --debug=netlink list ruleset
ip filter INPUT 2 
  [ counter pkts 0 bytes 0 ]
  [ immediate reg 0 accept ]

table ip filter {
    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }
}
# lsmod | grep nft_compat
#
```

Almost anything else will (until the userspace and kernel version allow to translate it into native *nftables*, so this possibly depends on the *iptables* version and the kernel version for a given rule).

```
# iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
# lsmod | grep nft_compat
nft_compat             20480  1
nf_tables             286720  4 nft_compat
x_tables               61440  2 nft_compat,ipt_REJECT
nfnetlink              20480  2 nft_compat,nf_tables
# nft --debug=netlink list ruleset
ip filter INPUT 2 
  [ counter pkts 8 bytes 608 ]
  [ immediate reg 0 accept ]

ip filter INPUT 3 2 
  [ counter pkts 0 bytes 0 ]
  [ target name REJECT rev 0 ]

table ip filter {
    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 8 bytes 608 accept
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
    }
}
#
```

Any entry displayed by `nft --debug=netlink ...` that includes either `target name` (for `iptables-nft .. -j` *target*) or `match name` (for `iptables-nft ... -m` *module*) means it's using the corresponding `x_tables` kernel module through the `nft_compat` compatibility module.

To get rid of it, don't use `iptables-nft` at all or tools using their libraries (libip4tc2, ...) . Of course reverting to `iptables-legacy` (if even provided?) would be worse: this one is intended to become deprecated upstream, and the compatibility layer intended to be kept for a long time to replace it instead.

This probably means: don't use Docker, don't use podman, don't use ...

Conclusion: I don't see how you can get rid of this message.

Comment: Since getting rid of podman/containers isn't practical I'll have to put up with the message.  I'll like for a way to silence the message for now.  (In the future I'm sure podman/docker will move dependencies to nftables).